# Converting some values of a json string to double in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following php code:

```
'fees' => number_format($_POST['fees'],2)
```

The sample JSON is:

```
{
 "fees":"74.00"
}
```

I need the value for fees to be a double rather than being a string.

I tried doing this:

```
'fees' => (double)number_format($_POST['fees'],2)
```

But it does not seem to work.
Is there any way to make fees a double rather than it being a string?

Comment: Use `(float) $_POST['fees']` instead

Comment: In json it should always be a string, _hence the term JSONString_ you need to convert it to whatever, whereever you actually process that number, presumably in javascript

Comment: It should work fine: https://eval.in/634143

Comment: @Yonel using `(float) $_POST['fees']` does not seem to type cast integers

Comment: @Bert that code returns an integer

Comment: @deantaz `(float) "74.00"` always returns `74`, maybe you need do this `number_format((float) $_POST['fees'], 2)` but this returns again a `string` "74.00", so I don't see the difference?

Comment: @deantaz In JSON there's no difference between 74.00 and 74, so it uses the shortest form

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the string value to float , you can use following code. But in Json it should be a string .

```
$string='123.56999';
$float  =   doubleval(number_format($string,2));
var_dump($float);
```